# i have problem with python package '' deep matcher " installation

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, matching, string-matching

hello i want to install python package for [deep matcher](https://github.com/anhaidgroup/deepmatcher) with pip, and i get this problem

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==0.3.0
>   (from deepmatcher) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1 No matching
>   distribution found for torch==0.3.0 (from deepmatcher)

**i use python 3.6**

my pip command **pip install deepmatcher**

Comment: What exactly have you tried until now? What command is returning the error you posted?

Comment: pip install deepmatcher

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue before and I fix it by
installing 'torchtext==0.2.3'

Answer (score 0):

In Google Colab, run

```
try:
    import deepmatcher
except:
    !pip install deepmatcher==0.1.2.post2
    !pip install torch==1.10.0 torchtext==0.11.0
```

Then importing as below should work.
Note that for the first time, after running the first installation cell, you need to restart the runtime before running the second cell to make it work.

```
import deepmatcher as dm
```